# AngularJS get next $state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hey guys I wrote this code to do a front end check (I already checked in server side). To see if user is logged or not depending in the "State" it is or path in this case, because I was using the `$location` first, but I moved to `ui.router`. Any suggestions of how to make this code work with `ui.router`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, checkLogin, User) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    checkLogin.check(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        var nextUrl = next.$$route.orginalPath

        if (nextUrl == 'login' || nextUrl == '/') {
          $state.target('panel')
        }

        $rootScope.isLogged = true;
      } else {
        $rootScope.isLogged = false;
        $state.target('login')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use localStorage, store that there in a user object, then do an if check on that guy.

Comment: `$stateChangeStart` handlers don't work well with asynchronous APIs. Asynchronous callback-based APIs should be converted to return promises and be used in the `resolve` property of target states.

Comment: you could try using resolve method on $state, where it is defined.